# Initialize an array that will have multiple value types in Swift

Tags: ios, arrays, xcode, swift

How would I be able to initialize an array that will contain multiple value types.

Usually, I'd initialize it by typing this:

```
var array = [Int]()
```

Comment: Could you give a specific example of an array with multiple value types?

Comment: How about `var array = [Any]()`?

Comment: @Leo you should post your comment as the answer so the OP can accept it. (You beat me to it)

Comment: Since when comment has become substitute for answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Any`

```
var array = [Any]();
array.append(1)
array.append("1")
```